# How to make videos same shape and height

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, html5-video

I have uploaded two videos to the database and Its being displayed on my website. I am trying to make them the same shape and height. The width is fine, but one of them is shaped like a square and the height is longer while the other is rectangle and the height is shorter and I know its because of the way video was taken, one was taken vertically and the other horizontally. How do I get them to be the same shape and height. Can you help me please?

```
     I tried this 

    <video class="video1" id="cb" preload="auto" video="src="{{$proo->video}}#t=1""   style=" height:80%; max-height:20em; width:100%; max-width:20em; object-fit: cover; 
 float:left; clear:both; 
     padding-left:2%;  margin-top:0px;     cursor:pointer; "><source="video1.jpg" playsinline alt="Video Unavailable"   id="" ></source>
  </video>

      this the javascript part to  handle the onclick,onmouseleave


  $(document).on('mouseover touchstart', 'video', function() { 
        $(this).get(0).play();
        this.muted=true;
    }); 



    //pause video on mouse leave
    $(document).on('mouseleave', 'video', function() { 

        this.currentTime = 1;
        $(this).get(0).pause(); 

    });

    $(document).on('click touchstart', 'video', function() { 
        $(this).get(0).play();
        this.muted=false;
        this.currentTime = 0;

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a little something i came up with when i need to output YouTube videos in iframes and its very responsive meaning that it adjusts its height and width in relation with current screen size.

```
<style>
       #mediaPlayer{
        position: relative;
        height: auto;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        padding-top: 1.875em; 
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 0.1875em double #185875; 
        background-image:url('../video_loading.gif'); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
       }

    #mediaPlayer iframe{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;   
    }
</style>

/*use the div to specify the exact height and width you want*/ 

<div style="height: 50%; width:50%;">
 <center>
  <div id="mediaPlayer">
    <iframe id="play_now" width="100%" height="100%" src="source here" value="value here" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
 </center>
</div>
```

The `video_loading.gif` background is usually a good idea for users with slow network to have something in the background while your iframe content is loading

but you have to find your own unique gif file/image and set it's location in the `background-image:url('../file-location-here.gif');`

Comment: is the iframe the only way to do this?

Comment: No there are other ways but iframes are usually the way to go when it comes to responsive video sizing, you can replace the iframe in the above code with your `<video>` tags but be sure to exclude your `<style>` tags else it will over write the current style

Comment: Okay I'm trying the Iframe but I need to play the videos one by one and it also starts playing automatically which I don't want.I need to play only when clicked and my browser keeps asking me if I want to download the video to my computer and I don't know why

Comment: Are you're asking for a play, pause, next, previous button a sort of media player control? Cause they are plugins for that and lots of such answers on stack just search for it :)

Comment: well not like that but more so like onclick play video on mouse leave stop. That's what I have now in my code but it does it for the video. I edited my code so you can see what i'm talking about

Comment: Switch the 'video' to 'iframe' in your jquery code. Am not a jquery fan. Killing mosquitoes with a sledgehammer is not my style.

Comment: Lol Ok. Thank you so much for taking your time out to help me. I really do appreciate it. I will still accept your answer because I think I need to use an Iframe  and your answer gave me an idea.