# WordPress video embed code width increase doesn't work

Tags: php, css, wordpress, embed

Using this code to increase width of embedded videos on WordPress, but after doing this nothing changes:

```
[embed width="756" height="420"]...[/embed]
```

What is the proper width increase for WordPress embedded videos?

Comment: Are you sure there is no external CSS applied to it?

Comment: You can follow this link https://millionclues.com/wordpress-tips/fullwidth-responsive-youtube-embeds/

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embed_Shortcode): "_The Embed feature allows you to wrap embedded items using a simple Shortcode to set of a maximum (but not fixed) width and height._" This only sets the max width.

Comment: that article didn't work. can anyone check the url: NSFW https://vidz.vintagepornbay.com/2018/09/22/milf-and-her-guy-find-themselves-alone/ maybe this css already has fixed video embed?

Comment: Consider just using css to make your own responsive video window [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52453489/how-to-make-videos-same-shape-and-height)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a container around your iframe and make it responsive:

`<div class="responsive-embed">[embed ... ]myvideo.com[/embed]</div>`

```
.responsive-embed {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 55%;
 padding-top: 15px;
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.responsive-embed iframe {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No. Still nothing changes.